# Greasemonkey: extract 3 parameters from JavaScript and build URL

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need to extract parameters of vars 'id', 'Name', 'ds' from JavaScript (in this example "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chatData__ = {id:'aaa',Name:'bbb',ds:'ccc'};
```

Then I want to build URL with extracted params and open it in new tab:  "www.mysite.com/script.php?id=aaa&name=bbb&ds=ccc"

Thank you for help!

Comment: im beginner, so i dont know which command to use to extract variable values from JS, so i didnt try a thing yet.

Comment: Derek: can I use one of these: getElementById()   getElementsByName()  or  getElementsByTagName() ?

Comment: problem is solved with help of javascript.ru helping hand